# Escape Stacking Context of z-index

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem with a couple of parts. The first part is that I need an absolute positioned `:after` element to be visible above a fixed position element. The second part is that I need to be able to have a modal as a child of that fixed element that will cover the whole screen. Here's a simplified version of my app.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='nav'></div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='modal'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 0;
  border-left: solid 10px black;
  border-top: solid 10px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
  }

.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

A codepen: https://codepen.io/winterblack/pen/ypBOqz

I can either have a `z-index: -1` on my content element, or a `z-index: 1` on my nav element. Either way, it gets in the way of the modal, which must have the content element a its parent.

The best solution I can think of right now is to use `z-index: -1` on the content element, and remove it when the modal is opened. That will have the strange effect of having the absolute element disappear while the modal is opened...not too big of a deal probably, but not ideal. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the position of `content` to relative, would that be an ok compromise for what you're trying?

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    width: calc(100vw - 100px);
    background: aquamarine;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I will accept this answer. I was also thinking of giving it no background and adding an element behind everything with the right background color, but this works.

Comment: Quick note, I wound up using my own method because this method changed the positions of the children of content too much. The other solution was to add a background to what would be body here, remove the background from content, and remove the z-index from everything but modal.

Comment: Thanks for following up on it. That's actually why I presented my answer as a question. I knew that changes with the position value can have other consequences, so it is really to test out if it fits the situation. Glad you worked out a more optimized solution.

Comment: Your solution does solve the problem as presented, so it deserves to be accepted.